# error installing xmms on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, xmms

I want to install XMMS media player on UBUNTU 12.04. I'm following instructions, but when type ./configure I receive message bellow:

*** The glib-config script installed by GLIB could not be found**
 If GLIB was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
 **your path, or set the GLIB_CONFIG environment variable to the**
 full path to glib-config.
configure: error:  **GLIB >= 1.2.2 not installed - please install first ***

I installed libglib2.0-dev, but still continue to receive this message.
What have to do and where to find this glib-configv script ?

Answer (score 0):

XMMS requires glib version 1.2 series libraries (2.0 series will not work). You can get sufficiently new version of *that* from levien's PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:levien/thbio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libglib1.2-dev libgtk1.2-dev
```

But even then you'll likely run into problems with undefined references in libgdk 1.2.